# PHP match most outside set of brackets

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

```
$sample = <<<EOD
lots of gibberish
before what I want{{Template
| x = 1
| y = 2|z= 3}}more gibberish
here too. {{Other|test}}
EOD;
```

I'd like to get rid of the gibberish and just get:

```
$sample = <<<EOD
{{Template
| x = 1
| y = 2|z= 3}}
EOD;
```

I'd normally look for "{{Template" and end with "}}", but my problem is, it might look like this sometimes:

```
$sample2 = <<<EOD
lots of gibberish
before what I want{{Template
| x = 1
| y = {{Convert|1|2}}|z= {{Convert|3|4}}}}more gibberish
here too. {{Other|test}}
EOD;
```

In this situation, it opens and closes some curley brackets, but I want it to match this:

```
$sample2 = <<<EOD
{{Template
| x = 1
| y = {{Convert|1|2}}|z= {{Convert|3|4}}}}
EOD;
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
\{\{Template[^\{]*(?:\{\{[^\}]*\}\}[^\{]*)*?[^\{]*\}\}
```

See the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/woWaYj/1)

---

**Explain**

```
\{\{Template                //Starts with {{Template
[^\{]*                      //Any chars except {
(?:\{\{[^\}]*\}\}[^\{]*)*?  //Any inner groups+trailing chars conditional
[^\}]*                      //Any chars except {
\}\}                        //Ends with }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\{(.*)\}/s
```

That should match the outermost brackets, including newlines in between.

```
(\{\{Template(.*)\}\})\w+/s
```

This will match the {{Template start with a }} followed by some gibberish. The "template" part will be stored in $1

Comment: Wouldn't that also include the "{{Other|test}}" in $sample?

Comment: Sorry, i skimped over a bit. I'll fix it.